# ngMaterialDatePicker Dependency injection fails during gulp serve:dist

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have used `ngMaterialDatePicker` which works fine in dev mode but when I tried to run using `gulp serve:dist` I am getting the below mentioned error can anyone tell me why it has a strange behaviour like this:

**Error:**

> Module 'ngMaterialDatePicker' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in uglyfing js code, do you use [ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-annotate) or [babel plugin](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate) for build command?